# Nested find on the basis of two conditions

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to find files that are starting with `show` and were created in a particular month. I have tried the following

```sh
for i in  `find /home/data -type d -name "$MONTH"`;
    do  find $i -type f -name "show*" -printf "%h\n"|uniq >tempfile1;
done;
```

but I get this error:

> `-bash: /home/data/testdata/2017/Apr/25: Is a directory`

How can I fix that?

Comment: please read formatting help!

Comment: I don't get this error on my Redhat 6.4. It works "as expected" and lists all directories with "show" inside them... be a little more specific on your system

Comment: Now its working fine but with another issue..Only the last listed directory has been listed in the tempfile1 or i have to append output in place of redirecting it with the following syntax...                                                 for i in  `find /home/data -type d -name "$MONTH"`;
    do  find $i -type f -name "show*" -printf "%h\n"|uniq >>tempfile1;
done;

Comment: So you fixed it! well done! Feel free to come back with another question.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find files whose name starts with "show" that have a path component that matches a particular string.  Matching the name of a parent directory is very different than matching a creation time.

Comment: It seems you would be better off with `find . -wholename "*/$MONTH/*/show*"`

Answer (score 0):

If you run that small bit through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net), several issues become apparent:

1. Instead of looping over the output of `find` use `-exec`
2. You should enclose `$i` in quotes to prevent globbing and word splitting. That may be the cause of your issue.